# Compilation fails due to  "The displacement must be greater than or equal to -32768 and less than or equal to 32767" with g++4.6.1 on aix6.1

Tags: c++, unix, g++, aix

I am trying to compile the c code with g++4.6.1 on aix6.1 using assembler version 6.1.

The compilation fails due to following:-

```
line 3954495: 1252-171 The displacement must be greater than or equal to
    -32768 and less than or equal to 32767.
line 3955281: 1252-171 The displacement must be greater than or equal to
    -32768 and less than or equal to 32767.
line 3955395: 1252-171 The displacement must be greater than or equal to
    -32768 and less than or equal to 32767.
line 3955401: 1252-171 The displacement must be greater than or equal to
    -32768 and less than or equal to 32767.
```

I compiled using following options:-

```
g++ -o tcl-int-cln.o -maix64 -bbigtoc -c tcl-int-cln.C
```

I compiled the same file using gcc4.0.2 on aix5.3. It worked fine.

It generally occurs when you try to compile large files using g++. I gave an option for that but the problem persists. Is this an assembler issue?

Could somebody throw some light on this or is it gcc bug or aix problem?

Any workaround?

Thanks.

Comment: Apparently, something is limited to the range of a signed 16 bit integer. However, without actually seeing the source code, it's hard to know what that "something" would be...

Comment: Is there some inline asm in the C code ?

Comment: @Lindydancer : It is a large file and it is difficult to paste the code here. Could you tell some technique to debug or need some other info?

Comment: Sometime the size of data types varies depending on the Operating System.

Comment: From what I can see on google, this is a gcc bug and you need to split your source file into something smaller.

Comment: @DaveRlz : It would be good if you go ahead with that and tell me something more because I have already given some option for it.

Comment: @PaulR: Since the above code works fine with gcc4.0.2 on aix5.3. How about building gcc4.6.1 with 5.3 assembler on aix6.1 and then tried compiling the code. The present version of assembler in aix6.1 is 6.1 and that in aix 5.3 is as5.3.  How feasible is this solution??

Comment: I am looking for some answer and somebody voted it down. You should read when you vote down for any question so that it should not deviate other community users and make this platform a good one. http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/vote-down

Comment: Wow, a 4 million LOC C source file. That's a pretty big source file. Hey, why aren't you compiling it with `gcc` instead of `g++`? Maybe it's just a C++ source file that ends with `.C`...

Answer (score 6):

[Known GCC bug](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=4587) since GCC 2.95. GCC can't handle big inputs; it will then assemble `ld r4,X(r3)` instructions (relative load, displacement `X`) where `X` is bigger than 16 bits. That's not allowed on POWER.

Comment: Wow, an error message, luxury. Last time I saw a bug like this wasn't in gcc, but another toolchain, and the result was that it in effect just masked the bottom 16 bits and used those as a displacement. Took a while to debug, especially since it was my second week of my first job.

Comment: Yah, I can relate to that. IIRC the original K&R compiler (the one at AT&T) had similar silent issues when your functions exceeded 32K. And of course you can't reduce these bugs to a small test example ;)

Comment: A function exceeding 32k probably wasn't a high risk at the time. My bug happened when the whole executable (actually image, since this was ARM embedded) exceeded a limit, so the specific function(s) it happened in had nothing to do with the problem other than being too far away from the address they were accessing...

Comment: @MSalters : I went through that bug and it is a duplicate of this http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=378. But I didn't find any workaround for that.

Comment: @MSalters : Since the above code works fine with gcc4.0.2 on aix5.3. How about building gcc4.6.1 with 5.3 assembler on aix6.1 and then tried compiling the code. The present version of assembler in aix6.1 is 6.1 and that in aix 5.3 is as5.3.  How feasible is this solution??

Comment: Pls read the above comment before vote up. The above code works fine with gcc4.0.2 on aix5.3 (POWER).

Answer (score 2):

I was using GCC and got this compile error.  Adding "-mcmodel=large" fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `-Wl,-bbigtoc` to your compiler flags. If that doesn't work, try adding `-mminimal-toc` as well.

Comment: Those options are only for the linker aren't they? In this case they won't help with the assembler error messages.